# Find start and end positions of all occurrences within a string in Python

Tags: python, string, window, position, range

If you have a sequence:

```
example='abcdefabcdefabcdefg'
```

and your searching for:

```
searching_for='abc'
```

what function would give you a list with all the positions?

```
positions=[(0,2),(6-8),(12-14)]
```

i created a window list that splits 'example' by 3 so it goes from 'abc','bcd','cde'

```
windows=['abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'def', 'efa', 'fab', 'abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'def', 'efa', 'fab', 'abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'def']
```

and used a for loop

```
for i in windows:
    if i == 'abc':
```

thats where i get stuck . . .

Comment: What you are doing is nearly tripling the memory required to represent that string. @miku has the perfect solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html); the match objects come with position information [attached](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start). Example using Python 2:

```
>>> import re
>>> example = 'abcdefabcdefabcdefg'
>>> for match in re.finditer('abc', example):
        print(match.start(), match.end())
0 3
6 9 
12 15
```

Comment: genius. i need to learn how to use these modules. i've only been experimenting with python for about 2 months

Comment: This would work except, this does not iterate the last position correctly unless -1 is used.

Comment: This solution is so good, but it raises an error when the substring contains parenthesis. :(

Comment: @EsraaAbdelmaksoud, that's because the string is interpreted as a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). If you want to match a literal parenthesis, you'll need to escape it, e.g. like `'ab\(c'` ...

Comment: @miku I already use it as \( and \), but for some unknown reason it kept raising an error with finditer(). However, it works perfectly with other functions.

Answer (score 4):

The re module provides what you need.

```
import re
print [(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer('abc', 'abcdefabcdefabcdefg')]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is elegantly expressed by a list comprehension:

```
positions = [(i, i + len(searching_for) - 1)
             for i in xrange(len(example))
             if example[i:].startswith(searching_for)]
```

Note that it's often more useful to have the end index point *after* the last character, rather than *to* the last character as you asked for (and the above code provides).