# Locate and extract a piece of string that contains a keyword from text in python

Tags: python

I am making a bot which is looking through many comments and I want to locate any sentence that starts with "`I'm`" or "`I am`". Here is an example comment( that has two sentences I want to extract).

```
"Oh, in that case. I'm sorry. I'm sure everyone's day will come, it's just a matter of time."
```

Here is the function that I have up to now.

```
keywords = ["i'm ","im ","i am "]

def get_quote(comments):
    quotes = []
    for comment in comments:
        isMatch = any(string in comment.text.lower() for string in keywords)
        if isMatch:
```

How can I locate where the sentence starts and ends so I can .append it to  the list `quotes`?

Comment: How you determine the end of sentence?

Comment: Have a look at `index` and `find` methods of your `str` instances. Another solution would be to use regular expressions. Have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459412/find-start-and-end-positions-of-all-occurrences-within-a-string-in-python#8459451).

Comment: @Kasramvd A `.` I think is best.

Comment: @kikocorreoso I thought about just finding the location of where the keyword is and then where a `.` is but then there is the example I gave which has more than one `I'm` and more then one `.` :/ So I have no idea what I should do

Comment: What about questions? And don't forget exclamations! Also note that any of these punctuation marks may occur _inside_ a sentence under various circumstances.

Comment: @PM2Ring You're right.. This is getting harder and harder.

Comment: Use regex as your condition within a list comprehension. `>>> [sent for sent in s.split('.') if re.match(r"i['a ]m",sent.strip(),re.I)]
[" I'm sorry", " I'm sure everyone's day will come, it's just a matter of time"]
`

Comment: @Kasramvd This will also match sentences starting with `I` and then a word starting with `m`.

Comment: @tobias_k Yep, there's a missed whitespace after `m`, it would be `r"i['a ]m\s"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) for this:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "Oh, in that case. I'm sorry. I'm sure everyone's day will come, it's just a matter of time." 
>>> re.findall(r"(?i)(?:i'm|i am).*?[.?!]", text)
["I'm sorry.",
 "I'm sure everyone's day will come, it's just a matter of time."]
```

The pattern I use here is `r"(?i)(?:i'm|i am).*?[.?!]"`

- `(?i)` set flag "ignore case"
- `(?:i'm|i am)` "i'm" or (`|`) "i am", `?:` means non-capturing group
- `.*?` non-greedily (`?`) matches a sequence (`*`) of any characters (`.`) ...
- `[.?!]` ... until finding a literal dot, question mark or exclamation mark.

Note that this will only work if there are no "other" dots, i.e. as in "Dr." or "Mr.", as those, too, will be treated as end-of-sentence.

Comment: Wow, that looks so simple. Some people are amazing, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Check if this code works for you

```
def get_quote(comments):
    keywords = ["i'm ","im ","i am "]
    quotes = []
    for comment in comments:
        isMatch = any(string in comment.lower() for string in keywords)
        if isMatch:
            quotes.append(comment)
    print "Lines having keywords are "
    for q in quotes:
        print q


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a="Oh, in that case. I'm sorry. I'm sure everyone's day will come, it's just a matter of time."
    #Removed last "." from line before splitting on basis of "."
    a = a.rstrip(".")
    list_val = a.split(".")
    get_quote(list_val)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>python demo.py
Lines having keywords are
 I'm sorry
 I'm sure everyone's day will come, it's just a matter of time

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you