# How to get the starting and ending indexes of word using re.compile and finditer() functions

Tags: python, python-re

For  a string like

comment = "**love programming javascripts!!**!"

I got the start and end indexes of '*script*' in 'javascript!!!' using re.compile() and finditer() functions.
I need to get the start and end indexes of the complete word 'javascripts!!!' that holds '*script*'.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459412/find-start-and-end-positions-of-all-occurrences-within-a-string-in-python

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Regex:

```
import re

string = 'love programming javascripts!!!'
p = re.compile(r'[\w!]+')

for i in p.finditer(string):
    if 'script' in i.group():
        print(i.start(), i.end())
```

You can alternatively use `p = re.compile(r'\S+')` for pattern. It depends on your need.

Answer (score 0):

How about without regex?

```
comment = "I love javascript!!!"

all_scripts = [word for word in comment.split() if "script" in word]

# Lets look for first relevant words start & end indexes

start = comment.find(all_scripts[0])
end = start + len(all_scripts[0]) -1

print(start, end)  # 7 19
```

The above code yields first word's indexes containing "script".

I you want all words' indexes instead of first word, try below instead of first

```
comment = "I love javascript!!!"

all_scripts = [word for word in comment.split() if "script" in word]

all_indexes = [(comment.find(word), comment.find(word) + len(word) - 1) for word in all_scripts]
```